# Chuseok is a big holiday in Korea

Tags: prepositions

> 1. Chuseok is a big holiday in Korea.
> 2. Chuseok is a big holiday of Korea.

Can we use both sentences? What is the difference between 'in Korea' and 'of Korea'? Does 'in Korea' modify 'a big holiday'? Does 'of Korea' modify 'a big holiday'?

Comment: The version with **in** would be much more idiomatic and common, so it's better to use **in**. The preposition **of** would look more natural in "a holiday of love" and similar phrases.

Answer (score 1):

Using **in** would be much more idiomatic and natural to a native speaker. "A big holiday of Korea" sounds more like a holiday celebrating Korea rather than a holiday that is part of the culture of Korea. When mentioning the people who celebrate the holiday, you could use "for" as in "a big holiday for Korean people."